# Pandas "groupby" substring and then aggregate features

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

Say I've got the following pandas Dataframe for 6 sessions of a game in which we record two scores, and also the members of the team.

```
ID |  Team                   | Score1 | Score2 |
------------------------------------------------
1  |  Alice, Bob, Charles    |    100 |     80 |     
2  |  Bob, Dylan, Eddy       |      0 |     40 |
3  |  Alice                  |     50 |      0 |
4  |  Bob, Eddy              |    150 |     80 |
5  |  Felix, Charles, Bob    |    100 |      0 |
6  |  Alice, Felix           |      0 |     40 |
```

The Team column is a string, we can have as many players as we want in the team (at least 1)

I'd like to perform a `group-by` like operation to have for all players (so kind of group-by "Players"), the matches they've been playing in. Result would be :

```
Group Alice:

ID |  Team                   | Score1 | Score2 |
------------------------------------------------
1  |  Alice, Bob, Charles    |    100 |     80 |     
3  |  Alice                  |     50 |      0 |
6  |  Alice, Felix           |      0 |     40 |

Group Bob:

ID |  Team                   | Score1 | Score2 |
------------------------------------------------
1  |  Alice, Bob, Charles    |    100 |     80 |     
2  |  Bob, Dylan, Eddy       |      0 |     40 |
4  |  Bob, Eddy              |    150 |     80 |
5  |  Felix, Charles, Bob    |    100 |      0 |

Group Charles:

ID |  Team                   | Score1 | Score2 |
------------------------------------------------
1  |  Alice, Bob, Charles    |    100 |     80 |     
5  |  Felix, Charles, Bob    |    100 |      0 |

Group Dylan:
ID |  Team                   | Score1 | Score2 |
------------------------------------------------
2  |  Bob, Dylan, Eddy       |      0 |     40 |
```

and so on. Some lines can then appear in several different groups.

My ultimate goal is to end-up with features computed on scores for each player. For example `meanScore1` or `maxScore2`, ie like :

```
Player  |  meanScore1 | maxScore2
---------------------------------
Alice   |          50 |        80
Bob     |        87.5 |        80
Charles |         100 |        80
Dylan   |           0 |        40
Eddy    |          75 |        40
Felix   |          50 |        40
```

I currently already have a Dataframe with the list of all possible players. Then I construct the above Dataframe using a loop but it is highly redundant and time-uneffective, but I expect there is a quicker way using `groupby` and `agg` logic. Is there?

Comment: Are you sure about your output for `Bob` in the first column?  Seems like it should be 350 / 4

Comment: That's correct, did the wrong calculation, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pandas` doesn't deal with values inside of strings or lists very well.  It prefers "tidy data".  Luckily, in `pandas` >= 0.25, you can use the `explode` method to turn nested data into tidy data.  Here, you can first split on string values, then `explode`, which leaves a simple aggregation operation.

---

```
d = dict(meanScore1=('Score1', 'mean'), maxScore2=('Score2', 'max'))
m = df['Team'].str.split(', ')

df.assign(Player=m).explode('Player').groupby('Player').agg(**d).reset_index()
```

```
    Player  meanScore1  maxScore2
0    Alice        50.0         80
1      Bob        87.5         80
2  Charles       100.0         80
3    Dylan         0.0         40
4     Eddy        75.0         80
5    Felix        50.0         40
```

Comment: Didn't know `explode`, will try, it looks neat anyway! I've got another layer of complexity on top of the first `groupby`, I'd like to compute aggregation only on time windows (for example aggregate scores of `Alice` on slots differing by at least 2hours). Would something like `df.assign(Player=m).explode('Player').groupby('Player').Time.rolling('2hours').apply(min).groupby('Time').agg(**d).reset_index()` be licit?